# How to create a moving slider using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to make an quiz wizard using jQuery. Here is the link which demonstrate what I want to do exactly: http://www.solesociety.com/quiz

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jQuery slider [Coda-Slider 2.0](http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/2.0/) for a quiz.

It's customizable and easy to use. Demo and source is given, and you can download either.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link for the same: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

It looks like you didn't want a slider but an image cycler. Here are some plugins for the same:

- [jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/)
- [Image Flow 0.9](http://cool-javascripts.com/effects/image-flow-09.html). [Demo](http://imageflow.finnrudolph.de/).
- [jqGalScroll](http://benjaminsterling.com/jquery-jqgalscroll-photo-gallery/) (photo gallery)

I hope these help.